# Update all the rows in a particular column PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

Hi I am trying to edit rows for a particular column 'PM2.5' using '''df.at['0', 'PM2.5'] = 10''' for first row of the PM2.5 column but instead of editing, it is adding a new row. The headers for the columns are defined by titles but my rows are numbered, how do I go around this? I want to do this for 18 rows and manually add data to the column PM2.5. Thanks!

Comment: It means there is different column, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your data frame with this kind of behaviour. so we can reproduce it at our ends.

Comment: ['Unnamed: 0', 'FreqVal[Hz]', 'Field[A/m]', 'Volume[cm3]', 'Mass[g]', 'kg_conv', 'up_mass', 'sus', 'KIm[SI]', 'KVol[SI]', 'KMass[m3/kg]', 'Ph', 'HolderRe[SI]', 'HolderIm[SI]', 'Range', 'normalised1', 'PM2.5' @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, so first index value is not `0` ? `print (df.index[:3].tolist())` ?

Comment: Unnamed: 0 FreqVal[Hz] Field[A/m] Volume[cm3] Mass[g] kg_conv up_mass sus KIm[SI] KVol[SI] KMass[m3/kg] Ph HolderRe[SI] HolderIm[SI] Range normalised1 PM2.5
0 0 976 200 10 0.0039 0.001 3.900000e-06 2.560000e-06 2.940000e-07 2.560000e-06 2.560000e-08 6.270 -0.000011 -3.220000e-07 2 0.656410 2.547494
1 1 976 200 10 0.0087 0.001 8.700000e-06 2.900000e-06 9.040000e-07 2.900000e-06 2.900000e-08 17.442 -0.000011 -3.220000e-07 2 0.333333 -1.452982

Comment: It is @jezrael. This is what I get [0, 1, 2] but there are two columns with zero value. I am trying to delete unnamed: 0 column from del df['Unnamed 0'] but its not doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comment problem is index values are integers (RangeIndex), so for set values need integer too.

So change `'0'` (string)

```
df.at['0', 'PM2.5'] = 10
```

to `0` (integer):

```
df.at[0, 'PM2.5'] = 10
```